# Mysql insert into duplicate key on a non-duplicate key

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, duplicates

I use PHP and Mysql.

**This SQL works:**

```
INSERT INTO products (id, title, description)
            VALUES (10, 'value1', 'value2')
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            id=10,
            title='value25',
            description='value2'
```

My `id` is a primary key and therefor it works. The other fields are varchars.

**My real case is a bit different. Look at this:**

Type is introduced and *together* with `sku` it's unique.

```
id    sku    title    description    type
1     abc                            one
2     abc                            two
3     def                            one
```

So my "real" key is the `sku` that I want to use and it's *not* unique by its own. It can not be in my case. But together with `type` it is unique.

**Look below and it might be more clear:**

```
abc-one // Unique combination
abc-two // Unique combination
def-one // Unique combination
```

Is it possible to use a multi insert/update SQL query in this case?

Comment: For my comprehension: How does your update query looks like without this example values? And what do you exactly mean with "multi query"?

Comment: @rbr94 My current update query is the sql on top of the question. It's an insert but also an update ` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: so why don't you post the real problem instead of a hypothetical one??

Comment: How do you want to react to a duplicate key event for your two unique columns?

Comment: @e4c5 This is my real problem. The only difference is that my sku looks like this: dc848d57-f459-4514-93bb-5649b22c648c` but it's harder to read so I made them simpler in this question.

Comment: Have you defined `sku` and `type` as `unique` columns?

Comment: @rbr94 If it's a duplicate, update, else insert. I'm considering to merge sku and type, and use that instead of id. Maybe that would simplify things. I'm not sure if long ids will slow down the selects?

Comment: @rbr94 No, sku can't be unique. Type can't be unique. Only together can they be unique.

Comment: Yes I considered that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the columns `sku` and `type` as `unique` columns, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` expression will also work as well as e.g. with only one `PrimaryKey` in your `products` table.

**Example (based on your data):**

```
id    sku    title    description    type
1     abc                            one
2     abc                            two
3     def                            one

//INSERT
INSERT INTO products (id, sku, type) VALUES (4, 'ghi', 'one') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... 

//UPDATE dataset with ID=1
INSERT INTO products (id, sku, type) VALUES (1, 'ghi', 'two') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... 

//UPDATE dataset with sku='abc' and type='one'
INSERT INTO products (id, sku, type) VALUES (5, 'abc', 'one') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

Therefore see the MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I did not want to complicate it more than needed so I've already merged them and set it as a new id without auto increasment. I don't think I will use the id later so it should be good for performance anyway. Thanks!